# RoR, Javascript - how to automatically update charts from table?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to make graphical representation of my data in my tables. I can get the data to be show on the charts but to do so I find myself having to code each record one by one like this:

Model:

```
def self.subject_analysis(subject_type)
      Note.where(:subject_type => English).count if subject_type == :English
      Note.where(:subject_type => Geography_Class_C).count if subject_type == :Geography_Class_C
    Note.where(:subject_type => Maths_Class_B).count if subject_type == :Maths_Class_B
```

Highcharts js

```
...
},
            series: [{
               name: 'Number of notes By Class Module',
               data: [<%= Note.where(:subject_type => 'English').count %>, <%= Note.where(:subject_type => 'Geography Class C').count %>, <%= Note.where(:subject_type => 'Maths Class B').count %>]
          }]
        });
```

This works but obviously this is far from ideal and not what I need. I would just like the charts to update from the table automatically when the table changes because a new record has been added.

Would appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use `data attributes`

define @my_var in controller

```
@my_var = Note.where(:subject_type => English).count
```

on view `<div id='english' data-note='<%= @my_var %>'>`

than in your js file

```
eng = $('#english').data('note')
```

and pass it to highcharts code

Comment: Thanks! But i'm wondering when I add a new class module to the table can I get the chart to update with that module without having to do anymore code? Do you see what I mean?    So when admin, for example, adds a new class to the table it just automatically shows on the chart. Thanks very much though.

Comment: which graph do you use @Co2

Comment: Column for this one. But also pie charts and line graphs. A mix. But for this one it's a column chart.

Comment: Anymore help anyone? :/